# textarea charcounter

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-ext

How do I make a label to show the charcount of a TextArea?
I have the following code:

```
public void onChange(Field field, Object newVal, Object oldVal){
    counterLabel.setText(textArea.getValueAsString().length() + "/160");
}
```

problem is I have to click the label for i to change the charcount.

help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
textArea.addKeyPressListener(new EventCallback(){
        @Override
        public void execute(EventObject e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
});
```

Use this EventCallback and in the execute method just use your method `counterLabel.setText(textArea.getValueAsString().length() + "/160");`

Answer (score 1):

Change the charcount when the users presses a key instead of when the textarea changes.

Maybe addKeyboardListener can help.